# Can we use Citus with Gorm?

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm, citus

We are trying to do distributed DB using PostgreSQL.
We came across Citus (https://github.com/citusdata/citus)
but we are using GORM as ORM for our backend.
Is it possible to combine both??

Comment: Citus enables you to shard your database to distributed nodes, based on a distribution column. As long as your ORM can take a `filter` condition for any operation that it does on db tables, you can use it with Citus. If you shard your db by `tenant` or `customer` id, then you should use that in `WHERE` clause in almost all db operations.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Do you know if GORM can do that?

Comment: You can execute raw SQL using GORM, so possible, see https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important things to consider is if your ORM supports composite primary keys, which are very common to use in Citus. GORM suppots these: https://gorm.io/docs/composite_primary_key.html, so I don't see any reason why it would not work.